Should I release bitmaps before deleting them?
After working with images, I'm very conscious of leaving unused objects laying around and not cleaning them up.  With that said, I have a situation where I have a list of bitmap images and at a later time find myself needing to clear the list of all it's objects.
The question: Should I be doing something other than just clearing the list?  Should I be destroying each bitmap object one by one first or does the garbage collector do all that for me like one might expect?

Bitmap implements IDisposable. You should always dispose any disposable objects.

Related.

If you are working with bitmaps extensively (destroying the whole list and allocating a new?), you shoould be aware about GC pressure, from my past experience running into OOM was easy without.

OK, so I guess the answer is "yes, manually dispose of all the bitmap objects in the list even though the GC will dispose of them later"?  Thanks @JonasH but I still don't understand if/why that's necessary.  I'm unclear if you're just talking good practice or necessity because I will see memory leaks otherwise.

The GC only handles managed memory, IDisposable is for any other resource, like file handles, or native memory. There is a finalizer, but it is non-deterministic and should not be relied upon. I would recommend reading about the dispose pattern if you are unfamiliar with these concepts.

Thanks for the follow up info @JonasH.  The way I see it is to use the GC as a "catch all my mistakes" (maybe) last resort.  :)
